# Google Analytics - Phone Orders Internally

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, analytics, magento, tracking

I am running an ecommerce site and currently have google analytics filtering out our IP.  While this gives almost absolute metrics about visitors it does not include orders processed internally because customers choose to call rather than checkout online.  Also our store is running on the magento platform.

What do you recommend to help track these orders and conversions via google analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a proxy site so that it appears as if you're coming from a different IP. You could either set your own up, if you have access to a different external IP from your ISP, or use one of the many proxies available on the internet.

Comment: while it would show for tracking purposes, it still does not help me define which customer checked out via phone.

Comment: You can use an include filter to filter all those transactions done via the IP address of your proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Google Analtyics apps gallery, it has about 20 integrations with the ability to track phone call tracking. See if its helpful.

Comment: thanks for the help.  i never knew google analytics had an apps gallery!